# pgr_dijkstra not returning anything when using the same vertex

Tags: pgrouting

I'm using pgRouting 2.3 and in the description of the [`pgr_dijkstra`](https://docs.pgrouting.org/2.3/en/src/dijkstra/doc/pgr_dijkstra.html#characteristics) function states that:

> When the starting vertex and ending vertex are the same, there is no
>   path. The agg_cost the non included values (v, v) is 0

[image]

My problem is that I need to use [`pgr_dijkstra One to many`](https://docs.pgrouting.org/2.3/en/src/dijkstra/doc/pgr_dijkstra.html#pgr-dijkstra-one-to-many)

```
pgr_dijkstra(edges_sql, start_vid,  end_vids, directed:=true)
```

And sometimes, the same `start_vid` node could be in `end_vids`. Yet `pgr_dijkstra` returns nothing for that pair of same nodes.
Do I have to validate if `start_vid` is inside `end_vids` before querying `pgr_dijkstra`?

Comment: Did you try? Does the *One to many* signature return nothing? It should return a set of records for all pairs it found a path for?

Comment: Could you post your code, or point to it on GitHub? How did you create your network? Osm? My experience with pgrouting is that it works very well on a correctly configured network, but fails if not correctly setup.

Comment: FIrst of all, why can't you check if the start vid is not in the list of end vids? This shouldn'tbe complicated. It obviously makes no sense to search for a route where start and end are the same. 
And second pgRouting 2.3 is not supported anymore for quite some time, and it would be really better to use the recent version because a lot has been improved.